# Vibrator not stopping in service

Tags: android

I have a service with the following code:

onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.vibrator = ((Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE));
}
```

onPhoneFlipMethod which listens to flip event of phone:

```
this.vibrator.vibrate(100);
```

vibrator is an instance variable declared as: private Vibrator vibrator;

Now the problem is when the phone is flipped, the vibrator keeps on vibrating instead of stopping after 100 milliseconds. Is it because the OS is sending the flip events time and again.

How can fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not positive why that's happening, but the first step to figuring out why it's vibrating too long would be to put some kind of debug code (breakpoint, Log.d, Toast, etc.) in the onPhoneFlip method that will let you know whether it is getting called constantly.

Comment: yup added a toast and I see that the onPhoneFlip method is getting called continously